# How to make a Text Blink when an notification appears and stop it when it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to blink the notification when its called from the server and need to stop when its Clicked..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#new_message").load('new_notification');
    $("#indi").load('indi');

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#new_message").load('new_notification');
        $("#indi").load('indi');
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<span class="label label-success" id="indi"></span> // Here the notification is shown the blink needs here
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="menu" id="new_message">
    </ul>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this [Jquery Plugin](https://antiyes.com/2009/08/24/jquery-blink-plugin/) .It has a blink and unblink functions .